# how Make radio button in symfony male and female two choice included

Tags: symfony

I've tried to write:

```
<?php
     add('gender',
         RadioType::class,array('choices'=>
                array('f'=>female','m'=>'male')
         )
     )
?>
```

But I received the following error

> "choices" is not Attriibute

Comment: Attempted to clarify and format question

Answer (score 2):

The radio type does not provide a way to choose between different options. To do that you have to use the [choice type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) with the [expanded option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#expanded) set to `true`:

```
$builder->add('gender', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array('female' => 'f', 'male' => 'm'),
    'choices_as_values' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the single quote `'`, its missing for `female` option :

```
<?php
     add('gender',
         RadioType::class,array('choices'=>
                array('f'=>'female','m'=>'male')
         )
     )
?>
```